# "undefined" before actual value in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, undefined

This is the code I use:

```
localStorage["FSS"] += JSON.stringify(favSongs);
localStorage["FSTS"] += JSON.stringify(favSongTitle);
localStorage["FIS"] += JSON.stringify(favImages);
```

But when I retrieve the values I get this:

For `FSS`: `undefined["0t0FGyhB6C8"]`

For `FSTS`: `undefined["SONIC SYNDICATE - Denied (OFFICIAL MUSIC VIDEO)"]`

For `FIS`: `undefined["https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0t0FGyhB6C8/mqdefault.jpg"]`

[image]

I don’t understand how and where the `undefined` comes from and how I remove it to log the results on my screen (now when I log it it says `undefined` as well).

Answer (score 3):

The `undefined` is what was already in `localStorage`:

```
document.getElementById('existing').textContent = localStorage[Math.random().toString()];
```

Because you use the `foo += bar` syntax, the script will:

1. Get the existing value of `foo`
2. Perform type coercion to make `foo` and `bar` compatible
3. Append `bar` to the existing value
4. Assign the combined value back to `foo`

If `foo` already contains `undefined`...

This appears to be an artifact of accessing the `localStorage` properties via the map accessor. If you used [the `getItem` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), you would receive `null` instead of `undefined`.

Since you're working with JSON, the simple string concatenation (string `+=`) won't work even if you already have a value. You would end up with `['foo-album']['bar-album']`, which is not valid. I would recommend getting the existing item *or* an empty array, appending your new item, then replacing the stored value:

```
var prev = localStorage.getItem('FSS') || '[]'; // get the existing value or the string representing an empty array
var data = JSON.parse(prev); // parse into an object
data.push('New Album');
localStorage.setItem('FSS', JSON.stringify(data)); // convert back to JSON and set
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But when I try it only gets the first one and then never adds one. I need / want to add 10 items to a list / array which I can retrieve later. How do I do that?